# How to access webview code in VS code’s DOM for UI testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, webview

I am trying to automate UI testing of the extension for VS Code that has certain actions brought out into the SideBarView section as webview, self-written HTML that I want to access via Selenium webdriver (I use vscode-extension-tester package that provides almost every API necessary and is fantastically helpful, btw).

There's no problem accessing html from VS Code's DevTools, for example a button is exposed as "vscode-button" tag inside a webview's "iframe" tag, so I assume finding it by xpath might work:

```
let webElement = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//vscode-button[contains(@onclick, "loadMarkers")]'));
```

But when I run Extension host for testing, its DOM does not contain webview code, so findElement() returns "undefined". If I understand correctly, it only has a reference to the webview tag with the pointer to vscode extension that handles webview content, so I have to switch to that webview somehow. Page source shows only "div" with webview link inside an "iframe":

```
<div id="webview-<id>"...
  <iframe name="<id>" class="webview ready"... src="vscode-webview...;extensionId=<id>...;purpose=webviewView"...></iframe>
```

Haven't found anything in VS Code API document, currently reading about Electron webview API to understand if there are any other suggestions.

Vscode-extension-tester API provides switching to webview context from a different object, however. So I wondered if there is a generic way to do so.
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-extension-tester/wiki/WebView

p.s. I began working on automated testing just a while ago, so I may miss something obvious (that would be great to have a solution at hand), but it looks like there are no easy ways to solve my problem at the moment. Would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.